# System call interception for fork system call

Tags: c, fork, system-calls, dlsym

I am trying to intercept fork system call, and calling that hooked forked via library call.

code for the library :

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
//#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int fork()
{
    printf("This fork is Hooked \n");
    int (*actual_fork)();
    actual_fork = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"fork");

    int x;

    if(x=fork())
    //if(x=(*actual_fork)())
    {
        printf("Priniting from parent\n");
        return x;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("printing from child");
        return x;
    }
}
```

The next call to fork is still calling unistd's fork even though i have commented the include to that file.

It is working fine with actual_fork call. But i dont understand the reason that, why next call to fork is not calling this file's fork ??

Comment: The function to be called is determined by the linker, not the compiler. #include's are just like writing more code in the same file: can't change linkage

Comment: @sinelaw OOps.. indeed.. but still that donot justify, why the next call is made to the libc fork ?

Comment: 1. How are you linking the program? 2. What did you expect to happen?